# PySpark foreachPartition - how to get the partition's data as Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

How can I use foreachPartition on a spark dataframe but instead of getting an iterator as the function's parameter get the records of the partition as a Pandas dataframe?

```
df.foreachPartition(function_on_partition)

def function_on_partition(partition: pandas:DataFrame):
    # do stuff on all records in the partition in the pandas dataframe
```